# Can I go back to my home country (Malaysia) with less than 1 month validity on my passport?

Tags: passports, malaysia, expired

My passport is expiring in one month and I am now planning to go back to my country, Malaysia. Can I travel back to my country with 1 month validity left on my passport? Should I take a direct flight or connecting? Please advise, thank you.

Answer (score -4):

With one month or less, your passport is not valid anywhere for travel, except to your home country. A direct flight is safer – the airline can't refuse you boarding – but a connecting flight might work if the transfer happens completely airside, and you don't need a transit visa.

But why risk it? Fly direct.

Also, you might want to ask the Malaysian consulate whether you could renew your passport with them. It would solve the problem altogether.

Comment: There are plenty of countries (e.g. the UK) which allow travel so long as the passport is valid on departure.

Comment: Passport validity is also usually not an issue for airside transits almost anywhere.